# Nuget package cannot be installed

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I set up a local nuget package repository and create a custom package.

I followed these two guides:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Hosting%20Your%20Own%20Local%20and%20Remote%20NuPack%20Feeds

http://nuget.codeplex.com/documentation?title=Creating%20a%20Package

and here is the nuspec file of my package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>NLog</id>
        <version>1.0.0.505</version>
        <authors>NLog</authors>
        <description>NLog</description>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="NLog.dll" target="lib"/>
    </files>
</package>
```

the package was successfully created and the package shows up the package library.

But nothing happens when I click "INSTALL".

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens when you try to install it from the NuGet Console window (i.e. 'install-package ThePackageName')?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there was an issue with package building (Maybe the dll file didn't make it into lib). Try unzipping the package (rename to zip and extract) and seeing what's inside. We've updated nuget.exe and have added a -v flag to pack so that you can see the contents of your package after you build. You can install it from the ci machine http://ci.nuget.org:8080/guestAuth/repository/download/bt4/.lastSuccessful/Console/NuGet.exe).